# Remote access to windows 7 command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, remote-access

I would like to gain access to a remote windows machine's command prompt from my mac, and in specific from the mac's terminal, the windows machine does not have remote desktop connection at as it is a Windows 7 Home Premium edition. Is there anything that allow me to do this? I am looking for something that is reasonably command-line driven.

I can install software onto the remote machine, to act as an interface, and I have done so with applications like Logmein, but this is quite graphical and I was looking for something that is command-line focused.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install OpenSSHD for Windows - this will allow remote "console" sessions.

If you looking for something very "unix-like" then you can install cygwin.

http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/installing-openssh-on-windows-7/

Comment: I tried this, and its not bad! But the end goal was to run R on a windows OS. However have found that the resulting R that is run from the command prompt is a bit different, as it doesn't run the '.Rprofile' file upon starting up. Perhaps it might be to do with the command to run R is 'R --vanilla'  when using ssh where as natively the command is just R? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes when you login you will need to configure the .sh file you login with to run R with the settings you require, but that's another question you asking. From ssh console you can run anything, you just need to configure it correctly (that is the environment settings)

Comment: Ok thanks for that, will probable set up another question once I've had a bit of a go at configuring it, do you have any suggestions in terms of potential resources to look at?

Comment: I think you need to seperate remote access as a concept from R. SSH allows you in, but R may require certain things to run, not sure what they are as I have never used R. But here is a link that might help you: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Windows-packages